# Granting access to authzTo attribute

Tags: openldap, proxied-authorization

I'm trying to grant certain accounts auth access to their `authzTo` attribute in order to allow [proxied authorization](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html#SASL%20Proxy%20Authorization).

I tried adding this ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {1}to authzTo by dn.children="ou=Special Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" auth
-
```

using the command `ldapadd -f perm.ldif -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W`

but got this error:

```
modifying entry "olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcAccess> handler exited with 1
```

using verbose output and turning up the debug level haven't given me any more clues.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized what I was doing dumb after working on some other permissions.  It should be `attrs=authzTo`, not just `authzTo` by itself.  And what I really wanted was

```
to dn.children="ou=Special Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=authzTo by self auth
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: OP explicitly asked about 'auth', not 'write' access, so this answer is not very relevant.

I realize that I'm 8 years late for this question, but I think that it needs to be noted that it's a bad idea to permit write access to own authzTo attribute.

> Source rules are extremely powerful. If ordinary users have access to
>   write the authzTo attribute in their own entries, then they can write
>   rules that would allow them to authorize as anyone else. As such, when
>   using source rules, the authzTo attribute should be protected with an
>   ACL that only allows privileged users to set its values.

(quote from https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/ldap_administration/sasl_SASL_Proxy_Authorization.html)

Comment: Where do see write access to the `authzTo` attribute? I can only find `auth` permission (authentication).

Comment: You are right, I must have misunderstood the question.